# AWS Lambda load content from DynamoDB display in HTML from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on loading an HTML page from S3, which will contain dynamic info from the database. I have found a little info on how to go about this and was wondering if this would be best done with templating from lambda or pulling the page into the lambda function and updating the HTML on the fly. I have been using python in the lambda function. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it's more efficient to use a templating mechanism in Lambda (Bundled and deployed with Lambda) unless you have a requirement to change the template more often (Where you can load the template from S3).

This way, it will reduce the time for the Lambda to execute, reducing the costs, where you only have to do the DynamoDB query to fetch the data.

Generally, for NodeJS I use [Lodash templates](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#template). You should be able to find a simple templating engine for Python which will allow you to separate an HTML template where you can bind the data retrieved from DynanmoDB.

Comment: Ended up using Jinja2 (because using python) to render a template in the lambda function from S3 and returned this from the lambda, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction:

For updating the html file stored in an s3 bucket using a lambda function, use the boto3 library. Use get() to read the file and put() to write: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
html = obj.get()['Body']
```

Now access dynamoDB to get the data for updating the html file
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('name')
... query() or get_item(), etc
```

Then write the changes to the s3 object:

```
obj.put(Body=html)
```

Finally, what will trigger the lambda function? To me it would make sense to have changes to dynamoDB trigger the lambda, which is configurable in the aws console.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of this, and there are likely errors, omissions, etc in the code snippets.

Comment: I am displaying a page with user specific information, which will be triggered from logging in. The user will enter the portal and once authenticated I will display the user specific info from dynamodb and update the html for the page with this info inside the lambda function. Therefore, the function will be called, I assume, through API gateway.

Comment: Hmm. If you want dynamic content, s3 is probably not the best bet. Instead, consider using API gateway with a lambda function and dynamoDB. See this article: https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/01/31/how-to-return-html-from-aws-api-gateway-lambda/